# How to handle a player who asks me never ending questions about roleplay things

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, problem-players, social

Recently I started up a new game. I recruited players, got them to make characters,  and was ready to have some fun with them.

One of the players keeps asking questions. They ask about every detail of their character, they ask about other roleplay systems, they ask about other characters they're generating, they ask about games and movies they're playing, they ask questions about the rules. It's a long, never ending barrage.

I regret inviting them into the game now, because it's such a drain being asked endless questions. I've told them to ask questions in the public discord or online, they agree, but they immediately go back to asking me more questions, in private messages on discord when they get some new idea. There's a certain amount of, politeness in helping them with their character and understanding the world, but their sheer volume of questions is getting tiring.

It's made worse by the fact that English isn't their first language, and often their questions are vague and confusing and not easy to answer.

We're involved in another game, and I need to remain reasonably polite, so saying "Go away and shut up." isn't a good option. What's a reasonably polite way to stem the tide of questions?

The game we are playing is Dungeons and Dragons fifth edition, so there are many knobs to tweak and play with on characters.

Comment: Thanks! If you have any questions or  confusion please check out  [this post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9184/im-confused-about-how-this-site-works-where-can-i-go-for-help) for how and where you can go to seek help/answers. For starters, you can ping me in a comment below this question by typing "@rubiksmoose [message]" and I'll do my best to help out. Just remember, we are here to help! We hope to see you around. :)

Comment: Remember folks, if you're answering then you should have dealt with (or been) a player like this. [Subjective answers still need support](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/how-do-we-appropriately-back-up-a-subjective-answer).

Comment: Neat question. It might help me answer if I knew more about the questions being asked (other than the fact that they're really frequent). For example, is this person asking about things they could look up themselves, or decisions they could make themselves? Or are they asking things only you could answer? Or what? Some example questions might help.

Comment: P.S. Sorry to ask a bunch of questions in a post about how to deal with people asking too many questions.

Comment: The answer below worked, so I am sated, but the questions are various minor rule aspects about ideas they have for character creation across several games, not just my own mostly.

I have dealt with children asking questions, but they're cuter and I don't mind them asking because they're lonely.

Comment: @Pettypoo heh, *tips cap* on response in re kids. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Text chat for question answering is a great opportunity for 'later'. You don't HAVE to respond immediately, but sending answers at a later designated time for yourself is a great way to both reduce the amount of time you spend, and have time to think about the questions.

If the player has a hard time with that (presses for an answer RIGHT NOW), it's perfectly fair to reply with, "This is not a good time, I can address your questions later X as right now I'm focusing on what's going on now." And by that I mean, say those words out loud (if playing in live voice games) or in public channels even though there's no questions there.

This has worked for me in a few other games, as well as in my day to day work.

The most important thing is to actually address them. Doing it all in one go will save you time, and probably reduce the amount of 'pressing' questions they have. It also helps them understand when the right time to ask the questions are.

If they keep pressing, ignore them for the extraneous questions. I know this isn't the nicest feeling, but you have X other players to interact with, which is presumably greater than 1. If this frustrates them, cheers, not your problem anymore, you have given your answer. Probably only do the ignoring for that sessions, and in later sessions use the same 'I'm busy' line, if they don't catch on after 3 or so, eventually nix the line and go strait to ignore until 'later'.

If they respond poorly to this, it's probably going to be a public display and other folks will have noticed so you can probably expect some support.

Comment: I personally ask lots of questions in Private Messages, I fully expect them to NOT get answered right away. Preferably before the next session would be nice, but even a response saying 'I need more time to think about/address that' makes me happy.

Comment: I assume you've experienced this yourself, either as the player or DM? Your answer would be improved by explaining how this suggestion has worked in your own experience.

Comment: Thanks @V2Blast. What level of explanation would be preferable? Would it be preferable to be written in a form that states those were the exact steps I took with a person rather than to abstract it out? Or would a separate 'these are the steps I took with someone and they started asking the questions later in one case, and in another told me it was fine if I answered the questions at a later time?'

Comment: The latter is more what I'm talking about. Basically, demonstrating that you've tried this suggestion, and explaining whether it solved the problem and/or what happened as a result.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while, thanks for the information I'll try and include it in the future.

Comment: If you feel you can improve your answer in some way, you can edit it at any time - Q&As here are meant to stand the test of time. Anyway, hope you stick around! :)